# How do I create a C# interface for T where T extends IComparable<T> and the interface extends IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, interface, where-clause, constraints, ienumerable

What is the C# equivalent to the following java construct:

```
interface LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Iterable<T>
```

I cannot do this the following way in C# because it is assumed that IEnumerable<T>belongs to where constraint:

```
interface LinkedList<T> where T : IComparable<T>, IEnumerable <T>
```

How can I do this in C# ?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you're asking here, but do you mean this? `interface LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable <T> where T : IComparable<T>`

Comment: Consider removing the generic constraint, and instead take a `IComparer<T>` when constructing your list. Use `Comparer<T>.Default` to create a default comparer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
interface IInterface<T> : IEnumerable<T> 
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // implementation here
}
```